# Finding the right word

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend dropped a few historic samurai names A, B and C. And then I mentioned D. He said that D came long after A, B and C. Is it proper to say D is a modern samurai compared to the three? Can I say that D was a more contemporary samurai at the time?

Comment: Do you mean "a modern Samurai *name*"?  You switch from talking about names of Samurais to talking about Samurais themselves, making it unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Have you looked up *modern*? Do you mean "modern" or "**more** modern"? Have you looked up *contemporary*? Why do you think that word might be useful?

Comment: Thank you. By names, I mean historic samurai figures. For example, samurais A, B and C lived in the 10th-15th century while samurai D came much later like around the 18th century. I'm looking for a word that can describe samurai D as being someone who came much later than the three old samurais in the much distant past. Modern gives me a feeling that samurai D is "more advanced" like in terms of living, clothing, or fighting techniques which may be the case but I really just want to use a word that would describe samurai D as a samurai who lived at a time long after samurais A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment under the question:

> Modern gives me a feeling that samurai D is "more advanced" like in terms of living, clothing, or fighting techniques which may be the case but I really just want to use a word that would describe samurai D as a samurai who lived at a time long after samurais A, B, and C.

[*Contemporary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporary) is also wrong, either being synonymous with the *modern* you don't want, or meaning that D lived at the same time as the others.

Try [**recent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recent):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : having lately come into existence : NEW, FRESH
>   **1 b** : of or relating to a time not long past

It could be used in the following way:

> D was a more *recent* samurai than the others.

Comment: Wow! Yes, that's what I wanted to say.Thank you very much, kind sir.